# On a curve every point of which is a point of ramification

Tags: reference-request, math-history, fractals

The title of my post is the same as the title of a known article written by Sierpinski where he introduced its famous triangle. In the book *Handbook of the history of general topology* by Lowen said that this curve was introduced trying to attack the concepts of cantorian curve and jordanian curve, he talks but don't prove some very interesting properties. The original paper was written in polish, I do not know polish.

There exist some version in English or some article that talks about the same propierties of the Sierpinski Gasket and proved it? I am really intrigued about this properties but I only find articles that mention them but there is not formal explanation.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe an English translation of the Polish paper (indeed, all his papers in Polish) is in Sierpinski's "Collected Works". I have a copy, but right now I'm in the middle of moving to a new house, so I won't have access to it for a week or two (or more, depending on when I get to opening that particular box of stuff). I seem to recall that a shorter version was published in C. R. Acad. Sci. (Paris), and in checking at the [JFM](http://www.emis.de/MATH/JFM/JFM.html) site, I see that it's on pp. 302-305 of [Volume 60](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/cb343481087/date1915).

Comment: I forgot to mention that the C. R. Acad. Sci. (Paris) paper is in French.